# Joint Scheduling Problem with Variables Arrival Times

Tags: np-hardness, polynomial-time, scheduling

The scheduling problem $1\bigl|r_j\bigl|\Sigma\,U_j$ is strongly NP-hard but when preemption is allowed the scheduling problem $1\bigl|pmtn,r_j\bigl|\Sigma\,U_j$ [becomes strongly polynomial](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.363.6537&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I have a similar problem to $1\bigl|pmtn,r_j\bigl|\Sigma\,U_j$ but the arrival times $r_j$ are variables. Precisely, the arrival time $r_j$ of job $j$ is given by its completion time on another machine.

**EDIT**
Here is the problem: I have a joint scheduling problem where there are two machines 1 and 2 and $n$ jobs. The jobs have two sets of processing times $P^1=\{p_{1}^1,p_{2}^1,\ldots,p_{n}^1\}$ and $P^2=\{p_{1}^2,p_{2}^2,\ldots,p_{n}^2\}$ where $p^i_{j}$ is the processing time of job $j$ on machine $i$. The jobs can be scheduled in a preemptive way and must be scheduled on machine 2 before their deadlines $d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n$.

I need to find a scheduling on machine 1 and a scheduling on machine 2 such that the number of tardy jobs on machine 2 is minimum. The completion time $C_j$ of job $j$ on machine 1 is equal to its arrival time $r_j$ on machine 2. Please see the figure below.

[image]

For every possible scheduling on machine 1, I have a set of arrival times $r_j$ and thus I can apply the polynomial time algorithm for $1\bigl|pmtn,r_j\bigl|\Sigma\,U_j$ and I select the one that gives the minimum number of tardy jobs. But, this clearly does not run in polynomial time since all possible scheduling on machine 1 is large.

Can this joint problem solved in polynomial time? Or is it NP-hard?

Comment: [Thanks, I've deleted my comments as they no longer apply.]